# JS setTimeout() alternative

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, settimeout

Like i explain [here](http://blog.mlefree.com/2016/02/settimeout-alternative-as-happy-new.html) , i can't use window.setTimeout() anymore and any window classical functions like clearInterval etc ...); but i need calling a JS block code as an async one.

That's why i used XHR request.

What is the best way to implement a smart alternative to window.setTimeout() with XHR ?

```
// Not working :(
setTimeout(function(){ 
  document.getElementById("messageTimer").innerHTML = "Happy New Year ! (old version)";
}, 10);

// with or without jQuery - but XHR
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/local/url/easy",
    success: function(html, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // a loop ?
            // timeout done ?
            document.getElementById("messageTimer").innerHTML = "Happy New Year ! (working version)"
 }});
```

My fiddle test : https://jsfiddle.net/mlefree/xzh3w2we/

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [jQuery version 3.0](http://blog.jquery.com/) [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate), which now uses `requestAnimationFrame`

```js
  // Creates a jQ object where elem set to index of [0]
  // a plain object with value of 0 `{to:0}`
  // call .animate() chained to the jQ object
  // Animates `{to:0}` value from 0 - 1
  // $({to:0}).animate({to:1}

var duration = 5000;
$({to:0}).animate({to:1}, duration, function() {
  // do stuff after `duration` elapsed
  $("#messageTimer").html("Happy New Year ! (working version)")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-beta1.min.js"></script>
<div id="messageTimer"></div>
```

Comment: What does this {to:0} and {to:1} indicate? Please clarify.

Comment: `$({to:0})` create a jQuery object where element at index `[0]` is the plain object `{to:0}`, we can call `.animate()` chained to the jQuery object which animates the `to` property from `0` to `1`

Comment: further reading on objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score -6):

What about something like this?

```
var delay = 10000; // milliseconds
var before = Date.now());

while (Date.now() < before + delay) {};

alert('The delay has passed!');
```

Also, you might be interested in the Promise objects. Which could give you somtehing like this :

```
var customDelay = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  var delay = 10000; // milliseconds
  var before = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() < before + delay) {};
  resolve('Success!');
});

customDelay.then(function(msg) {
  document.getElementById("messageTimer").innerHTML = "Happy New Year !';
});
```

---EDIT---
The Promise object is part of ECMAScript 6 so there will be backward compatibility issues.

Luckily for you, jQuery does have it's own implementation of Promises!
[Introduction to jQuery Promises](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/03/22/an-introduction-to-jquery-deferred-slash-promise/)

See this page for documentation. Implementation will be similar.

Comment: Thxs phenxd ! it should do the trick. Promise sounds as an elegant solution for async.

Comment: PB : promise not recognized with IE 9  :(

Comment: this isn't async even with Promise the while loop will freeze the UI and no other js will be executed while the loop is working

Comment: Oops. Should I remove my answer completely or edit it?